# azure blob storage static site hosting redirect to backend web app

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to host my SPA (vue) on azure blob storage an my backend (laravel) as an azure web app.

The frontend domain is:

```
domain.com
```

and the backend lives on:

```
api.domain.com
```

However, not all static assets are on domain.com ... Some assets such as uploaded files are hosted on the backend server.

How can redirect requests from azure blob storage to the backend server if the file is not found on the frontend? I could only find an option to define a 404 html. Can I somehow configure a web.config the way I can do it with webapps?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot config a web.config on static website hosting for Azure Storage.

***On a static website, webpages contain static content and JavaScript or other client-side code***

things like web.config are server side configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website